# Improve performance of an update with sub-query

Tags: sql, sql-server

My select below works fine although the performance is not good. And I think the problem might be that I repeat the sub-query below 9x and I'm sure that it can be improved.

I think the problem is that I repeat the following sub-query for each if the columns to update:

```
select top 1 
    gestor_transac.XXXXXXX 
from 
    gestor_transac 
where 
    CONVERT(date,gestor_transac.fecha_tran) <= CONVERT(date,gestor_val_pos.fecha_trade) 
    and gestor_transac.uid_producto = gestor_val_pos.uid_producto 
    and id_cartera = @Arg_ID_cartera 
order by 
     gestor_transac.fecha_tran desc
```

Could anyone have a look at it?

```
update gestor_val_pos 
set cantidad = (select top 1 gestor_transac.shabal
                      from gestor_transac 
                      where CONVERT(date,gestor_transac.fecha_tran) <= CONVERT(date,gestor_val_pos.fecha_trade) and gestor_transac.uid_producto= gestor_val_pos.uid_producto and id_cartera= @Arg_ID_cartera
                      order by gestor_transac.fecha_tran desc
                     )
        , coste_div_loc = (select top 1 gestor_transac.Coste_LOC_BAL
                      from gestor_transac 
                      where CONVERT(date,gestor_transac.fecha_tran) <= CONVERT(date,gestor_val_pos.fecha_trade) and gestor_transac.uid_producto= gestor_val_pos.uid_producto and id_cartera= @Arg_ID_cartera
                      order by gestor_transac.fecha_tran desc
                     )
         ,  coste_div_car = (select top 1 gestor_transac.Coste_CAR_BAL
                          from gestor_transac 
                      where CONVERT(date,gestor_transac.fecha_tran) <= CONVERT(date,gestor_val_pos.fecha_trade) and gestor_transac.uid_producto= gestor_val_pos.uid_producto and id_cartera= @Arg_ID_cartera 
                      order by gestor_transac.fecha_tran desc
                     ) 
        ,  POS_cum_Inflows = (select top 1 gestor_transac.TRAN_Cum_inflows
                      from gestor_transac 
                     where CONVERT(date,gestor_transac.fecha_tran) <= CONVERT(date,gestor_val_pos.fecha_trade) and gestor_transac.uid_producto= gestor_val_pos.uid_producto and id_cartera= @Arg_ID_cartera
                      order by gestor_transac.fecha_tran desc
                     )    
        ,  POS_cum_Outflows = (select top 1 gestor_transac.TRAN_Cum_Outflows
                      from gestor_transac 
                      where CONVERT(date,gestor_transac.fecha_tran) <= CONVERT(date,gestor_val_pos.fecha_trade) and gestor_transac.uid_producto= gestor_val_pos.uid_producto and id_cartera= @Arg_ID_cartera
                      order by gestor_transac.fecha_tran desc
                     )    
        ,  Descripcion = (select top 1 gestor_transac.descrpcion
                      from gestor_transac 
                      where CONVERT(date,gestor_transac.fecha_tran) <= CONVERT(date,gestor_val_pos.fecha_trade) and gestor_transac.uid_producto= gestor_val_pos.uid_producto and id_cartera= @Arg_ID_cartera
                      order by gestor_transac.fecha_tran desc
                     ) 
        , Custodio = (select top 1 gestor_transac.custodio
                      from gestor_transac 
                      where CONVERT(date,gestor_transac.fecha_tran) <= CONVERT(date,gestor_val_pos.fecha_trade) and gestor_transac.uid_producto= gestor_val_pos.uid_producto and id_cartera= @Arg_ID_cartera
                      order by gestor_transac.fecha_tran desc
                     )
        , Fecha_compra = (select top 1 gestor_transac.fecha_tran
                      from gestor_transac 
                      where CONVERT(date,gestor_transac.fecha_tran) <= CONVERT(date,gestor_val_pos.fecha_trade) and gestor_transac.uid_producto= gestor_val_pos.uid_producto and id_cartera= @Arg_ID_cartera
                      order by gestor_transac.fecha_tran desc
                     )
        , Fecha_vencimiento = (select top 1 gestor_transac.fecha_vencimiento
                      from gestor_transac 
                      where CONVERT(date,gestor_transac.fecha_tran) <= CONVERT(date,gestor_val_pos.fecha_trade) and gestor_transac.uid_producto= gestor_val_pos.uid_producto and id_cartera= @Arg_ID_cartera
                      order by gestor_transac.fecha_tran desc
                     )
                     where id_cartera= @Arg_ID_cartera and uid_producto= @Arg_UID_pr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, you want `apply`:

```
update gvp
    set cantidad = gt.shabal,
        . . .
    from gestor_val_pos gvp cross apply
         (select top (1) gt.*
          from  gestor_transac gt
          where convert(date, gt.fecha_tran) <= convert(date, gvp.fecha_trade) and
                gt.uid_producto = gvp.uid_producto and 
                gt.id_cartera = @Arg_ID_cartera
          order by gt.fecha_tran
         ) gt;
```

Then you want an index on `gestor_transac(uid_producto, id_cartera, fecha_tran)`.